# is the tls.Conn "goroutine safe" in golang?

Tags: ssl, go

I have a question:
Can I **tls.read** a tls connection in one goroutine, while the other goroutine is calling **tls.write**?
the code may like this:

```
func main() {
        tlsConn := tls.Conn
        go func() {
                tlsConn.read(...)
        }()
        go func() {
                tlsConn.write(...)
        }()
}
```

Comment: yes it is, have a look https://golang.org/src/crypto/tls/conn.go#L844

Comment: Check the docs beneath [`net.Conn`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn).

Answer (score 4):

tls Read and write are independent of each other.

Read and Write uses seperate mutex in and out respectedly.

Snippet from the source code

```
func (c *Conn) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    if err := c.Handshake(); err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    c.out.Lock()
    defer c.out.Unlock()
    .
    .
}

func (c *Conn) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    if err := c.Handshake(); err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    if len(b) == 0 {
    // Put this after Handshake, in case people were calling
    // Read(nil) for the side effect of the Handshake.
    return
    }

    c.in.Lock()
    defer c.in.Unlock()
    .
    .
}
```

Thus

1. You can write and read concurrently.
2. You can do multiple read concurrently but only one read will happen at a time.
3. You can do multiple write concurrently but only one write will happen at a time.

Comment: But, it is “c.in.Lock()” in the Read function, the source code is [c.in.Lock()](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/crypto/tls/conn.go?name=go1.4#896)!

Answer (score 3):

Input and output are [separated](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/crypto/tls/conn.go?name=go1.4#53) so they should not interfere. Concurrent calls to either [`Write`](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/crypto/tls/conn.go?name=go1.4#849) or [`Read`](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/crypto/tls/conn.go?name=go1.4#896) are guarded by a mutex lock.

Therefore, yes they are safe to be called in a concurrent manner.

Comment: Is "Concurrent calls to either Write or Read" and "Concurrent calls to Write and Read" the same?

Comment: `Write` and `Read` are independent so they do not interfere with each other. `Write` and `Write` / `Read` and `Read` are safe.